# Taking structure's inputs from a file and print it in C

Tags: c, file, structure, printf, scanf

When i try to print expectedRuntime variable , it prints the address of  expectedRuntime.
But i can print timeOfSubmission variable correctly . Can anyone help me please ?

```
struct process
{
int timeOfSubmission;
int remainingRunTime;
int expectedRunTime;
char processName[20];

};

int main()
{
FILE *myInput;
myInput = fopen("input.txt", "r+");
while ( !feof(myInput) )
{

    struct process * newProcess=(struct process *)malloc(sizeof(struct process));

    fscanf(myInput, "%s", newProcess->processName);
    fscanf(myInput, "%d", & (newProcess->expectedRunTime) );
    (newProcess->expectedRunTime)=(newProcess->remainingRunTime);
    fscanf(myInput, "%d", & (newProcess->timeOfSubmission) );
    printf("%s    ",newProcess->processName);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%d    ",newProcess->expectedRunTime);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%d  \n",newProcess->timeOfSubmission);
    fflush(stdout); 
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading `newProcess->expectedRunTime`, 
you are overwriting it with:

```
fscanf(myInput, "%d", & (newProcess->expectedRunTime) );
(newProcess->expectedRunTime)=(newProcess->remainingRunTime);
```

which has garbage as nothing has been written to `newProcess->remainingRunTime`.

Comment: I switched sides like : (newProcess->remainingRunTime)=(newProcess->expectedRunTime);and it really works.This little thing has ruined my whole project so far:)Thanks a lot!